# Problem with using recursion in a boolean operator

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm new to coding in c++. In this piece of code I'm trying to write function isPalindrome through recursion, however this error pops out:

```
/Users/peixin.yu/Desktop/code/palindrome.cpp:14:6: error: no matching function for call to 'isPalindrome'
if (isPalindrome(strn.substr(1,strn.length()-2)))
```

I'm probably making a silly mistake here, can someone please help me out?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(int n);

int main(){
    string res = isPalindrome(12321) ? "true" : "false";
    cout<<res;
}

bool isPalindrome(int n){
    string strn = to_string(n);
    if (isPalindrome(strn.substr(1,strn.length()-2)))
    {
        return (strn[0] == strn[strn.length()-1]);
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: `substr` is a string. `isPalindrome` takes an `int`.

Comment: btw the compiler error message should have told you the same. It should contain more information than what you included here.

Comment: Oh right I forgot to include the second error message. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that you have declared `isPalindrome` as taking an `int`. But you are trying to call it with a `string`, and the compiler is telling you that you cannot do that.

Here's the solution, write *two* versions of `isPalindrome` one that takes an integer, and one that takes a string.

```
bool isPalindrome(int n); // int version
bool isPalindrome(string n); // string version

bool isPalindrome(int n){
    string strn = to_string(n);
    return isPalindrome(strn);
}

bool isPalindrome(string strn){
    if (isPalindrome(strn.substr(1,strn.length()-2)))
    {
        return (strn[0] == strn[strn.length()-1]);
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

BTW you have another problem which is that your code has *infinite recursion* and so will crash when you try to run it. But I'll leave you to fix that one. It's a common mistake when you write recursive functions.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I thought I made some silly mistake! Thanks for the answers!